# how to track classes of Spring webflow

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

I have maven based application built on java spring webflow. Application interacts with many down stream applications, we use the dependency for down stream application to interact with them.

If i run an flow i want to capture all the classes which executed for particular flow so that i can identify which class used to call one flow including classes in JAR?

i tried to print the classes but it prints only those which are in my application but how can I print classes from the JAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your application is based on Spring, I guess you can easily output the call stack using Interceptor, some like "org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor". While it has some limitations since you cannot capture the execution of those methods called by other methods in the SAME class, in that case, using proxy would be an option, for example, you can generate proxied class based on CGLIB.

Hope it is helpful to you.